# "$f$ is asymptotically greater than $g$"

Tags: asymptotics

What's the notation for ranking functions in increasing asymptotic order? I saw a notation with $\prec$ earlier, but now I can't find it. Would the following notation be correct?

$$\mathcal{O}(n)\prec \mathcal{O}(n\log n)$$

Comment: Incidentally, the "correct" interpretation of big-oh is that they are *sets* of functions (and that $f=O(g)$ better be written $f\in O(g)$). In that light, $\subset$ is the natural notation

Comment: Sometimes people use little-oh to represent the case where $f$ is $O(g)$ but $f$ is not $\Theta(g)$.

Comment: Michael Burr, you are right for monotonic functions or some other classes, but not in general. E. g. $f(x) = x (1 + \sin^2 x) = O(x)$, but $f$ is neither in $\Theta(x)$, nor in $o(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Donald Knuth, Oren Patashnik, and Ronald Graham in their textbook "Concrete Mathematics" (chapter 9) really use this notation for functions (not for sets of functions):
$$f(n) \prec g(n) \iff \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0. \tag{9.3}$$
This notation was introduced by Paul du Bois-Reymond in 1871. Also, as noted in the comments, you can write the same relation as $f(n) = o(g(n))$ meaning that $f(n) \in o(g(n))$. However $f(n) \prec g(n) \iff g(n) \succ f(n)$, but relation $\color{red}{o(g(n)) = f(n)}$ is invalid. Swapping $f$ and $g$ leads to $g(n) = \omega(f(n))$ or $g(n) \in \omega(f(n))$.